# How to access the text property in masterpage so that navigation to other pages in website is possible?

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to redirect to another page in my website. I have a textbox and a search button in my masterpage.The txt1.text should be the redirection url to be used to navigate to other pages. But i am unable to access the value in txt1.txt in my masterpage.

Please find the code below:-

```
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" Height="22px" Width="139px" class="searchtextbox"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="searchicon">
  <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Search" class="searchicon" onclick="Button5_Click"/>
</div>
```

In my masterpage, i have the code as follows:

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        Response.Redirect("txt1.Text"+".aspx");
    }
}
```

but the value in txt1 is null..

Please help me.

Comment: You have a security problem here: "never ever trust user input!"

Comment: I am unable to access the txt1.Text property. What is the issue I am facing here?